Odoo - KeyError when export
I am getting the following error when I try to export any data from odoov12. It is working fine in my local machine. And facing issues in staging and production server
I am using odoo12. How can i fix it?
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo12/OCB/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 88, in lookup
    r = d[key]
  File "/opt/odoo12/OCB/odoo/tools/func.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo12/OCB/odoo/tools/lru.py", line 44, in __getitem__
    a = self.d[obj].me
KeyError: ('hr.attendance_status', <function BaseModel._is_an_ordinary_table at 0x7f3b46b8d9d8>)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo12/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 80, in wrap
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo12/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1507, in index
    return self.base(data, token)
  File "/opt/odoo12/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1451, in base
    if not Model._is_an_ordinary_table():
  File "<decorator-gen-1>", line 2, in _is_an_ordinary_table
  File "/opt/odoo12/OCB/odoo/tools/cache.py", line 93, in lookup
    value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo12/OCB/odoo/models.py", line 631, in _is_an_ordinary_table
    return tools.table_kind(self.env.cr, self._table) == 'r'
  File "/opt/odoo12/OCB/odoo/tools/sql.py", line 47, in table_kind
    return _TABLE_KIND[cr.fetchone()[0]] if cr.rowcount else None
KeyError: 'FOREIGN'

